# Load 3D models on globe or 2D map

Tags: openlayers, cesium, 3d-model

I'm using ol3, ol3-cesium for creating 2D map & 3D globe.
These things are getting used at backend

1) tinyows 
 2) map server
  3) postgis

Now I want load 3D models on my map and globe. Lots of things are available, but i don't know which one to use.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Cesium supports glTF models in 3D, and support for models in 2D mode [is under development](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/pull/3764) as of this writing, planned for Cesium 1.22 in June 2016.

Comment: thanks. Is there any other way to store models in database and than use wfs to load model from database. [cesium-buildings](https://github.com/Oslandia/cesium-buildings) Here is some information but its not complete.